# What does this statement mean?

Tags: unity, c#

I am new to Unity as well as programming, I came across this statement and couldn't comprehend what it meant,

```
var result = numX != lastnumX || numY != lastnumY;
```

Can anyone explain how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Basically this should be read as:

var result = (numX ***not equal to*** lastnumX) ***or*** (numY ***not equal to*** lastnumY);

the result is boolean value, i.e. either True or False.

P.S. while it's certainly possible to ask such questions, this question shows that you lack pretty basics of the programming, you should get a C# programming book/course to familiarise yourself with it before you continue.

Comment: Why not use if statement?

Comment: @noobie sometimes an if would be the right choice. It depends on the context in which we're doing this check, but it's hard to speculate about that from just that one line alone.

Answer (score 1):

- `!=` means "does not equal"

  So `numX != lastnumX` evaluates to the `boolean` value `true` if `numX` is different from `lastnumX`, or `false` if both variables are the same.

  The same applies for `numY != lastnumY`
- `||` (double pipe) is a "logical or" operator - it checks whether *at least one* of the expressions on either side of it is `true`

  First it evaluates the expression on the left, and if it's `true` then the result is `true`

  (It does this without even checking the expression on the right - this is called "short circuiting" and it's useful to bail out of expensive or invalid checks if an earlier check tells you everything you need to know)

  If the expression on the left is `false`, then it checks the value of the expression on the right, returning `true` if it's `true` and `false` otherwise.

So inferring from the variable names, `var result` is a `boolean` variable that holds the value `true` if either `numX` or `numY` have changed values since "last time," and `false` if both numbers have stayed the same.